# How to modify my own ethereum node to mine transactions from my DAPP which uses ERC20 tokens?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, mining, dapp-development, dapps

Could someone please explain the below,

I am developing a DAPP which uses ERC20 tokens that already deployed in the mainnet. In order to mine the transactions for these ERC20 tokens, How I can use the ethereum node..?, I am planing to mine the transactions using my own ethereum node!! is it possible..? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, sure it's possible. But you still need a large amount of mining power. This is because, even if you're only mining your own transactions, they still have to be sealed in a block. For the block to be added to the ethereum chain, a lot of mining power is required.

Comment: what about using infura..

Comment: How would you propose doing that?

Comment: I am not familiar with Infura, Even if i use infura also I need to provide gas right..
?

Comment: Infura will just propagate your transaction into the network, so that miners can include them in blocks. The miners will only do that if they get paid in gas